# npm overhead - how to handle this?

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs, gulp, npm-install

When installing anything via npm, it downloads dozens of not needed files. Usually I am looking for a library final build, a `*.min.js` file or anything like that but the rest is useless.

How do you handle all these useless files? Do you remove them by hand or generate the final app with any build tool like `gulp` or `grunt`?

I'm quite confused as I have plenty of npm modules installed in my webapp and the folder size is about 50 megabytes but it could be 2mb only.

Comment: I'd say you are better off using gulp, if you are using npm to install stuff. That way, your final build should only have what it needs.

Comment: The issue is not npm. It's library developers including tons of unnecessary garbage in their builds, sometimes because of poor understanding of how npm works. If you use one of these libraries, you are required to download all dependencies as well.

Comment: @GOTO0 that's bad. Lodash for example, has 564 files in one folder

Comment: Personally I keep npm as a manager for dev processes, whereas code you are requiring for dist copies, such as a minified js file, I use bower for. Most high-profile libs include their own bower tasks that just include the concat src and dist copies of the final lib, although you could clone a whole repo if need be. Then yes, grunt or gulp copy task to copy the dist file into your desired folder on build.

Answer (score 3):

`npm install --production`

Just doing an npm install brings in both development and runtime dependencies. You could also set the ENV to production globally for the server: `npm config set production`.

See [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1434) github issue. Note that this won't get you *only* the final minified build of everything, but will greatly reduce the bloat. For instance, a library might rely on babel-cli, babel-preset-es2015, and uglifyjs to be built (devDependency), but you don't need any of that if it also includes the transpiled minified file.

Answer (score 1):

**Managing Packages**

For front end non-development packages I prefer [Bower](http://bower.io/). It maintains the minified and non-minified version of your packages.

**Build Tool**

Use either [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). Gulp would be my tool of choice.

Gulp task that will greatly improve your code are:

- minification of both css and js
- optimization/compression of images
- concatenation and caching to reduce the number of calls to the server
- package versioning
- automatic injection of project dependencies
- automatic injection of external dependencies
- static analysis of js and css
- automatic builds on code changes
- deployment
- testing

**Node**

If you can, leave to node all your development tools and leave to bower all your release plugins. Most node packages that are used in released apps have a bower installation counterpart.

***Edit***

---

Don't delete anything from Node manually as you don't know which packages have other packages as dependencies. If you are afraid that you may have junk in there, use npm rimraf to delete the node_modules folder, and then run npm install. Most importantly check your package.json for unnecessary saved packages.

Comment: I'll stick to my example with lodash - bower installed hundreds of files also, same like npm but with other fiel structure.

Comment: @Tukkan, you don't have to worry about the number of files that you have in your dev environment. You are using Gulp or Grunt right? Then use wiredep and inject to manage your depencies automatically